# TSQL Split XML nodes

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I query a table that looks like this:

```
DECLARE @test as table (
    [Id] int,
    [Changes] XML
    )

insert into @test VALUES (1,'<insert pk="1"/><insert pk="2"/><delete pk="1"/><delete pk="2"/>')
insert into @test VALUES (2,'<insert pk="3"/>')
```

To get this output?

```
1, <insert pk="1"/>
1, <insert pk="2"/>
1, <delete pk="1"/>
1, <delete pk="2"/>
2, <insert pk="3"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    XmlChanges.query('.')
FROM
    @test
CROSS APPLY
    Changes.nodes('/*') AS Nodes(XmlChanges)
```

The resulting output would be:

```
ID  (No column name)
1   <insert pk="1" />
1   <insert pk="2" />
1   <delete pk="1" />
1   <delete pk="2" />
2   <insert pk="3" />
```