# convert all fields and values to a single string

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

@HABO gave me this snippet:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_exec_connections as EC inner join
sys.dm_exec_sessions as ES on ES.session_id= EC.session_id
where EC.session_id = @@SPID
```

I want to combine all fields to a single nvarchar, i can put into a log-table

Like

```
field1: value1 (+chr(13)+chr(10)+)
field2: value2
...
fieldn: valuen
```

without having manually typing all the fieldnames and casts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could append `FOR XML PATH('')` on the end of the query and you'll get the result as one large XML string.  After that you can use XML parsing to split it up.  See the [documentation on the FOR XML PATH clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx) and a [StackOverflow question that is related to parsing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000160/tsql-split-xml-nodes).

Here is some sample T-SQL that produces the output you want:

```
declare @xmlblock xml
select @xmlblock = (
    select
        * 
    from
        sys.dm_exec_connections as EC inner join
        sys.dm_exec_sessions as ES on ES.session_id= EC.session_id
    where
        EC.session_id = @@SPID
    for xml path('')
    )
```

declare @logline nvarchar(max)
set @logline = ''
select
    @logline = @logline 
        + XmlChanges.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)')
        + ': ' 
        + XmlChanges.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
        + char(13) + char(10)
from
    @xmlblock.nodes('/*') as Nodes(XmlChanges)

select @logline

Output looks something like:

```
session_id: 52
most_recent_session_id: 52
connect_time: 2013-06-12T15:05:48.607
net_transport: TCP
protocol_type: TSQL
...
```